# grep to see if a line ends with a particular string

Tags: grep, string, text

Hello I have a file that has a lot of lines that end with `main.css">`, and some of them are repeated.

I want to keep only one copy of these lines and delete the repeated line.

Could I use grep to search if a file has a line that ends with `main.css">` ?

So far I have :

```
 grep ' main.css' file.txt |sort | uniq -u
```

This does nothing as I expected, it just gives me a blank output. Please help?
 This did not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
grep -n 'main\.css">$' file.txt
```

`$` denotes the end of the line, obviously, nothing can follow after this.

You do not need the `*` here, as you are searching for the pattern within the line, everything in front is automatically neglected if your pattern is found. The only thing you need to escape here is `.` which is the only regular expression operator in `main.css">`. Also `-r` is redundant when you supply only one file.

Comment: Guys please check the edit. :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk also,

```
$ cat file
foo main.css">
ghj
brar main.css">

$ awk '/main\.css">$/{print NR}' file
1
3
```

Or `sed`:

```
$ sed '/main\.css">$/=' file
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted as well to keep also other lines which are not having `main.css>` even if those were duplicates:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 1
Line 2 main.css">
Line 2 main.css">
Line 3 
Line 3 main.css">
Line 4
```

So that after the command you would get:

```
Line 1
Line 1
Line 2
Line 2 main.csv>
Line 3 
Line 3 main.csv>
Line 4
```

In this case below command should do the trick:
    `sort your_file | awk '!/main.css">$/;/main.css">$/,/main.css">$/{if($0!=p){print;p=$0}}'`

Answer (score -2):

```
sed  '/main.css/d' file.txt  > ~/Desktop/solution.txt
```

That worked perfectly fine :)

Comment: This will delete the lines rather that print the line numbers (and not just the ones that _end_ this way as per the question). If this is what you wanted to accomplish maybe you could edit your question to actually ask that.

Comment: Actually now that I checked, it did not work as I expected, it deleted the line which had `main.css` but I want it to delete `main.css">`

Comment: Please update your question with a more explicit description of what you have and what you want to have happen to it and I'm sure we can make it happen.

Comment: Hey @Caleb I have updated the question. :/